# How to write this method which allows to update the article with the Java Server Faces JSF 2.2 Framework based on the MVC pattern?

Tags: jsf-2.2

*Hi all!

I am on a JSF project for stock and sales management based on the MVC pattern.

I wanted to update the article ie the quantity in stock decreases by the quantity sold.

To do this, I have the classes Article (idArt, designation, qte_stock), Sale (idVte, date), ArticleVente (idArtVte, unitprice, quantity, # idArt, # idVte) and in particular their controller and service (here it is acts of facade for example the case of the class Article, the service is ArticleFacade etc.)

I need your help to do this!

Thank you in advance!*

Comment: This is not what I expected. I need your help to do this method which allows the updating of the article ie the quantity in stock must decrease by the quantity of the sales lines. Finally is someone there to help me ...?
thank you in advance

Comment: Thanks for your clarification!
Otherwise my problem was how to write this method ie the code.